# Is there a symbol in FA/FSM for everything else

Tags: finite-automata, notation

I remember in a Computability Theory class building a state machine for an assignment that required many 'go-back' transitions on $\Sigma - symbols$ for all symbols not already handled. This was very verbose and seemed to be a thing people would run in almost all states in any sort of parser.

Is there an agreed-upon shorthand symbol or notation for this? I didn't see it in the paper for Statecharts where I'd expect to find most useful missing notation.